# Some geometry about the proof for circumcenter

Tags: geometry

$\triangle ABC$ is an acute triangle. $P$ is a point inside $\triangle ABC$, $R$ is the radius of its circumcircle.(**$S$ Here means the area.**)

$P$ satisifies:
$\dfrac{S_{\triangle PBC}}{PA^2}+\dfrac{S_{\triangle PAC}}{PB^2}+\dfrac{S_{\triangle PAB}}{PC^2}=\dfrac{S_{\triangle ABC}}{R^2}$
.

How to prove that P is the Circumcenter of $\triangle ABC$?

I try to take the circumcenter $P'$ (which satisfies the equality obviously), and then prove $P=P'$.

It's obvious that $P'C=P'B=P'A=R$, which means:

$S_{\triangle PBC}\dfrac{P'A^2}{PA^2}+S_{\triangle PAB}\dfrac{P'C^2}{PC^2}+S_{\triangle PAC}\dfrac{P'B^2}{PB^2}=S_{\triangle ABC}$

With $S_{\triangle ABC}=S_{\triangle PBC}+S_{\triangle PAB}+S_{\triangle PAC}$, I have :
$S_{\triangle PBC}(\dfrac{P'A^2}{PA^2}-1)+S_{\triangle PAB}(\dfrac{P'C^2}{PC^2}-1)+S_{\triangle PAC}(\dfrac{P'B^2}{PB^2}-1)=0$

Now I am stacked at the following part(except the condition that those factors are all zero, which means $P=P'$). How to prove this problem?

Comment: To be clear: $S_{\triangle ABC}$ means the *area* of $\triangle ABC$ (as opposed to, say, the *semiperimeter*). Correct?

Comment: Yes, S here means the **area** of the triangle. I am sorry for not knowing the short for semiperimeter  issue :-(

Comment: By my (and *Mathematica*'s) calculations using barycentric coordinates, the set of *all* points $P$ satisfying the relation is a degree-six curve with an isolated point at the circumcenter. The curvy part of the curve lies outside the triangle, so the fact that $P$ is inside will need to figure into any argument. (The acuteness requirement guarantees that the circumcenter, too, is inside.)

Comment: It might be helpful to know about the standard of the question (Undergraduate, or Olympiad-type).